# Is there an simple to get a certain element from an array and place that element to the last place?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I'm working on my Web App, and I have a need for an array. That array contains objects. I need to check all the elements in that array with a for loop, and, if one of them meets the conditions, take that element, do what I need to do with that element, and place it to the last position in the array. Like this:

```
let myArray = [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}, {obj4}, {obj5}];
```

For example, if `{obj3}` meets all the conditions, I need to place it to the last place, like this, so the array looks like this:

```
myArray = [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj4}, {obj5}, {obj3}];
```

`{obj1}` meets all the conditions:

```
myArray = [{obj2}, {obj4}, {obj5}, {obj3}, {obj1}];
```

etc.

Comment: Why would you deal with obj3 first, and then obj1? Are you iterating backwards? That specific output order is clearly important.

Comment: Does the loop start afresh once a condition is met?

Comment: Please follow guidelines before asking the question on  stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the values except that particular value and than place that value at end,

this example is considering all the values are unique in your array

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

let findAndPlaceAtLast = (value) =>{
  let temp = arr.filter(e=> e!=value)
  return [...temp,value]
}


console.log(findAndPlaceAtLast(4))
console.log(findAndPlaceAtLast(2))
```

If there are multiple values which matches the condition then based on your desired output you can select one index ( or even more than one ) you want to remove filter the array and add the values at end in similar way as above example

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an index, you could take [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for getting the item and for pushing the item to the array.

```
array.push(...array.splice(index, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(arr);

ele = arr[1] //save match element in a variable
arr.splice(1, 1); //splice array and remove that element
console.log(arr);
arr.push(ele); // push element in array again
console.log(arr);
```